# Open and show the linux terminal?

Tags: java, linux, terminal, console

I'm opening and showing the default windows command prompt in java:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C dir & start cmd.exe /k dir ");
```

Works nicely!

But i was wondering if i can do the same thing on linux (in a windows x environment) with the linux terminal? (please note that the terminal/console should become visible to the user, accept input and such, not just run hidden in the background)

Comment: This is pretty hard in linux because there isn't a default terminal, most systems even come with multiple installed at the same time. You can try starting `xterm`. But the terminal the user likes the most will be his personal preference, so it is smart to add a config setting for this.

Comment: @Ferrybig Starting xterm by default (with optional override for user) shouldn't be a problem. But does the default (xterm) support starting a second terminal, cause when i start xterm with java (like above code) it starts hidden, in other words doesn't accept user input.

Comment: Whilst it is true what @Ferrybig says I certainly would _not_ call that "pretty hard". Many solutions simply try the three typically installed approaches, some detect what desktop environment is present which indicates what the preferred terminal emulator is and last not least one typically has a specific target system in mind where one knows exactly what emulator one wants to start.

Comment: @arkascha cheers! Do you mind sharing the "typically installed approaches" (just the names are enough, we can figure out the rest), it would be a nice addition to this post ;-)

Comment: Well, I'd try them in this order: `gnome-terminal`, `konsole`, `guake`, `yakuake`, `xterm`. There are more, but one of those _certainly_ is available. Note however that this will not solve your issue with the window not popping up since that is not an issue with a specific emulator (xterm in your case), but with the additional permission layer implemented in the traditional X environment. Note that unlike MS-Windows all unixoid environments (so Linux too) are multi user environments. Sounds like your process does not have access to the active graphical display.

Comment: It might also be a good idea simply to consult the `$TERM` environment variable of your process. It should name the preferred terminal emulator as defined for that account or situation. Or you have to adjust it accordingly when setting up your login shell environment.